# Website on GCP cant be reached on some wifis

Tags: nginx, web, google-cloud-platform, dns

I am using GCP, nginx and domain name from "name.com" to deliever my website.
It can be reached on mobile network but doesn't work with wifi.

Although on some wifis you can reach my site with around ~60% (from those i have tests) you cant.

It might have to do something with DNS / DNSSEC but its litearly a guess, I am clueless.

Comment: Use an Internet DNS testing site to find problems with your DNS resource record setup. I use MxToolbox. If you recently changed your DNS settings you will need to wait 24 to 72 hours typically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey everyone so I have found the problem.
When I looked online for best practice its recommended to use different ports for the backend and frontend.

apparently the port used for the backend was blocked by some routers.

Now the backend and frontend use the same port and it is fixed.

Hopefuly it will help other people who are getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try lower the TTL to 300 seconds for your domain in name.com? It could be that DNS has an old cache which did not yet point to your nginx instance/location. Or you could wait out the default TTL which is probably 12-24 hours.

Comment: Changing the TTL will have no effect on existing DNS resource records until they expire.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but apparently it was port problem.